# Spark View Engine and cache

Tags: caching, castle-monorail

I have the following action in the controller:

```
[Cache(HttpCacheability.Public, Duration = 86400, VaryByParams = "*", VaryByCustom = "url")]
public virtual void SearchForm(TModel form)
{
    ...
}
```

in this case view is cached, but when i change data through admin panel, view get from cache.

Is there a way to reset cache when i changed data?

Answer (score 0):

The `Cache` attribute you decorated your action sets a response header telling the browser client to cache the results.

This has nothing to do with spark view engine, it would behave the same way if you were using a different view engine.

The only way to clear the cache is to do so in your web browser.